# SugarCE : How to update a table field based on a changing time condition

Tags: sugarcrm

I use SugarCE v 6.5.4 . I need to update the status of a database table field based on the
time condition in database table data . Check every 5 minutes for condition and if met Update status of table . How it can done ? please reply me with a solution.

Thanks,
Anes

Comment: what have you tried(share your code)?and which field you want to update to database?

Answer (score 0):

You can join your suagrcrm DATABASE from the as400 or main tables with directly pass values in the any mySQL database.

Or another way to update manually from IMPORT in PHPMYADMIN.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a scheduler thats runs every 5min and that does the query and action you want. take a look at http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/09/07/adding-your-own-reoccuring-jobs-to-the-scheduler/